# r - ggplot2 - geom_text - horizontal values above geom_text do not have the same horizontal displacement

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am enclosing a sample dataset via dput and the commented `data.table` to ask a question about the horizontal displacement of text using geom_text.

```
library("data.table")
library("ggplot2")

# prevs2

dput(prevs2)
prevs2 <- structure(list(V1 = c("XY02", "XY03", "XY04", "XY16", "XY17"), 
    V2 = c(1L, 15L, 4L, 1L, 1L), N = c(66L, 130L, 55L, 3L, 17L
    ), Prevalence = c(0.0151515151515152, 0.115384615384615, 
    0.0727272727272727, 0.333333333333333, 0.0588235294117647
    ), LCL = c(0.00180338800237566, 0.0804738966923874, 0.0443506970334619, 
    0.28182217271425, 0.0331125475431457), UCL = c(0.0284996423006546, 
    0.150295334076843, 0.101103848421084, 0.384844493952417, 
    0.0845345112803837)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x003e2498>)
```

prevs2 is shown as a `data.table` below:

```
#     V1 V2   N Prevalence         LCL        UCL
# 1: XY02  1  66 0.01515152 0.001803388 0.02849964
# 2: XY03 15 130 0.11538462 0.080473897 0.15029533
# 3: XY04  4  55 0.07272727 0.044350697 0.10110385
# 4: XY16  1   3 0.33333333 0.281822173 0.38484449
# 5: XY17  1  17 0.05882353 0.033112548 0.08453451
```

The following `ggplot2` code produces the figure shown below.

```
ggplot(prevs2, aes(x = reorder(V1, -Prevalence), y = Prevalence)) +
geom_col() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LCL, ymax = UCL), width = 0.1) +    
xlab("V1") + ylab("Prevalence") + geom_point(aes(y = Prevalence)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90), 
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) + 
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "pt")) + geom_text(aes(label =
N), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), vjust = -0.9, hjust = -0.9)+ 
theme(text = element_text(size = 12, family = "sans"))
```

Is there anyway to modify the above `ggplot2` code to have equal horizontal displacement from the errorbars for each of the 5 geom_cols in the figure?

If not, is it because the horizontal distance is determined by the length of the text (for example, 130 is farther right than the other values)?

[image: ggplot2 barplot image in .png format]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hjust = "left"` so the left edge of the text lines up with the errorbar. Then `nudge_x` to move it away a bit:

```
ggplot(prevs2, aes(x = reorder(V1, -Prevalence), y = Prevalence)) +
    geom_col() + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LCL, ymax = UCL), width = 0.1) +    
    xlab("V1") + ylab("Prevalence") + geom_point(aes(y = Prevalence)) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(1.5), angle = 90), 
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "grey50")) + 
    theme(plot.margin = unit(c(2, 2, 2, 2), "pt")) + 
    geom_text(aes(label = N),  
              vjust = -0.9, hjust = "left", nudge_x = 0.1)+ 
    theme(text = element_text(size = 12, family = "sans"))
```

I removed `position_dodge` as I don't think it was actually doing anything, you only have one bar per x-value.

Result:

[image]